# How to show entire article content as a single-article module?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, module-display

I'm trying to add two pieces of content to a page, an article and an custom HTML menu. I've set the page to type of featured articles and created a module from a single article. How can I have this article display in it's entirety, not just the intro text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was a "read more" buried in the content and removing that solved the problem.